# Grafos Orientados Circulares com Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, grafo

Alguém sabe se é possível criar grafos orientados circulares com Mongodb ou preciso de um banco especifico orientado a grafos como o neo4j.

Nó A (A liga com B)

Nó B (B liga com C)

Nó C (C liga com A)

A->-B->-C->-A (fechando o circuito)

Comment: Você pode até utilizar algum plugin por exemplo como mongo connector para Neo4j.

Comment: Muito obrigado Jhonathan !

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro tentar Neo4j, pois ele é próprio pra isto e utiliza estruturas de json assim como no mongodb.Você pode até utilizar algum plugin por exemplo como mongo connector para Neo4j que ja transfere os dados do mongodb pro neo4j.